# Jquery FullCalendar get event id by jquery events

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I'm using [FullCalendar plugin](https://fullcalendar.io/) in order to show daily calendar.
When the user clicks on an event I want to get the calendar event id.
I did that by the FullCalendar click event:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    ...
    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, View)
    {
        console.log(calEvent.id);    
    }
});
```

I want to get the same event id by using JQuery events:

```
$('.fc-event').on('click', function(){
    console.log(...) //How do I get the the FullCalendar event id?
});
```

I'm very flexible in what way to do that - Get the id from the .fc-content with JQuery or bind some id in the events themselves and then show it when needed.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem.
Bind the id when the calendar events are rendered:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    ...
    eventRender: function(event, element)
    {
        element.find('.fc-content').attr("id", event.id);    
    }
});
```

And then you can use JQuery events by the id attr

```
$('.fc-content').on('dblclick', function(){
    console.log($(this).attr("id"));
});
```